# Updating an object property doesn't work in an enumerable

Tags: c#, list, ienumerable

I defined an `Order` class as following:

```
public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string OrdNumber { get; set; }
}

var dict = new Dictionary<int, string>();
  
dict.Add(1, "ORD1");
dict.Add(2, "ORD2");

var orders = dict.Select(a => new Order { Id = a.Key, OrdNumber = a.Value });
```

I wrote following code to update `Order` number:

```
foreach (var ord in orders)
{
    ord.OrdNumber = ord.OrdNumber + "*";
    Console.WriteLine(ord.OrdNumber);
}
```

The code execute as I expect, the output is:

```
ORD1*
ORD2*
```

but if I add following `foreach` after the `foreach` shown above:

```
foreach (var ord in orders)
{
     Console.WriteLine(ord.OrdNumber);
}
```

the result is:

```
ORD1
ORD2
```

The complete code is :

```
var dict = new Dictionary<int, string>();
dict.Add(1, "ORD1");
dict.Add(2, "ORD2");

var orders = dict.Select(a => new Order { Id = a.Key, OrdNumber = a.Value });

foreach (var ord in orders)
{
   ord.OrdNumber = ord.OrdNumber + "*";
   Console.WriteLine(ord.OrdNumber);
}

foreach (var ord in orders)
{
   Console.WriteLine(ord.OrdNumber);
}
```

and the output is :

```
ORD1*
ORD2*
ORD1
ORD2
```

Adding `.ToList()` to end of following line:

```
dict.Select(a => new Order { Id = a.Key, OrdNumber = a.Value })
```

fixes the problem. The output will now be:

```
ORD1*
ORD2*
ORD1*
ORD2*
```

Can anyone explain why this happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`.Select()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=net-5.0) returns a [`IEnumerable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerable-1?view=net-5.0), which is a sequence playing, in your case, `a => new Order { Id = a.Key, OrdNumber = a.Value }`

Every time you'll `foreach` the `IEnumerable`, you'll play that sequence.

Now, when adding [`.ToList()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tolist?view=net-5.0) it *materialize* the sequence in a List, by creating and keeping the objects. When you `foreach` the List, you don't play its creation sequence, but what its values actually hold, that's why in that case `ord.OrdNumber = ord.OrdNumber + "*";` is keps when using a `List`